# Android Studio JDK location

Tags: android-studio, location, java-6

I am having an issue with my android studio. Whenever i open it ,it throws an error

```
"Invalid Project JDK".
```

I have deleted my previous version of `Java` and installed a new version. I also tried to change the `JDK` location directory for new version, but it is not solved. Help in this regard will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

TRY to reset your Java and Android  `Environment variables` configurations.
You can input `Java` and `Javac` in your `cmd` to check whether your "Java Path" is  correct. Then input `adb` in your `cmd` to check whether your "Android Path" is correct.
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I did the same and it is working perfectly fine now.